# Self join to limit the resultset before the rest of the joins are executed

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a Table A with millions of records. This table must be joined to N more tables; I will only have one row returnded, as I will query by A key.

So in a traditional way I do something like this:

```
Select A.field1, ... , N.fieldN 
From A 
Inner Join B on A.fieldFkB = B.fieldKeyB 
... 
Inner Join N on A.fieldFkN = N.fieldKeyN
Where A.fieldKeyA = 'keyToFind'
```

But it takes a long time (as I have millions of records on Table A)

A partner told me to rewrite the SQL by removing the where clause and do a self join on table A like this:

```
Select MAIN.field1, ... , N.fieldN 
From A as MAIN
Inner Join A as AUX on MAIN.fieldKeyA = 'keyToFind' AND MAIN.fieldKeyA = AUX.fieldKeyA
Inner Join B on MAIN.fieldFkB = B.fieldKeyB 
... 
Inner Join N on MAIN.fieldFkN = N.fieldKeyN
```

And it works (it is faster), but I wonder...

There are any caveats that I am not aware of?
Is it a good practise to do this in this concrete use case?
Are there other alternatives?

Comment: Note that tables have _rows_ and _columns_. (Not records or fields.)

Comment: I'd stick with your WHERE clause. I'd expect exactly the same performance, but putting filtering conditions in the WHERE clause is clearer.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? And what happens performance-wise if you execute each query twice?

Comment: Is there an index on A.fieldKeyA in place?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: It is Snow flake, and yes, all tables have proper indexes

Comment: By pushing up the predicate from the where clause into the join condition you're passing fewer records into the hash join.  By passing fewer records you're doing less work and less work often means quicker/cheaper.